# dynamically set countries for supported locales in express application

Tags: node.js, express, coffeescript

i am using node-cldr library (https://github.com/papandreou/node-cldr) for localization and have an options list for the countries, http://pastebin.com/jyM5pCLn

```
territoriesList = cldr.extractTerritoryDisplayNames('en')
countries = _(territoriesList)
              .pairs()
              .filter (pair) -> isNaN(pair[0]) 
              .zipObject()
              .value()


app = express()
maxAgesOption = { maxAge: 86400000 * 30 }
if not config.server.compressAssets then maxAgesOption.maxAge = 0
i18next.backend(gettextSync)
i18next.init(i18nextOptions)
i18next.registerAppHelper(app)
app
  .use( '/css', express.static( "public/css", maxAgesOption) )
  .use( '/js', express.static( "public/js", maxAgesOption) )
  ...
  .set( "countries", countries )
```

At the moment, i am setting `'en'` in `territoriesList = cldr.extractTerritoryDisplayNames('en')` how do i push the lang-code to this from the request?

I had this

```
.use (req, res, next) ->
      code = i18next.lng().substr(0, 2)
      territoriesList = cldr.extractTerritoryDisplayNames(code)
      countries = []
      regions = []
      territories = __.each territoriesList, (value, index, list) ->
        if (isNaN(index))
          countries[index] = value
        else
          regions[index] = value
```

but this is doing it for every request, as it is added like a middleware, and middleware will run even for every request, even for image/css request.

but since these values are not going to change between requests, only when the user changes the language, it shouldn't be middleware?

any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use middleware. Middleware will be executed according app.use declaration position. If you send user css or image without language rotation, add this middleware after .use( '/js', express.static( "public/js", maxAgesOption) );

For performance issue you can use any memory cache storage, for example Redis. Always get user language code from memory storage, when user update his settings, just change value into memory storage for this user.